# Django - "no module named django.core.management"

Tags: python, django

I get the following error when trying to run Django from the command line.

```
File manage.py, line 8, in <module>
     from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named django.core.management
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to run, what version of Python, version of Django etc...?

Comment: The version of my local host is Python 2.6.6, and 1.4.3 Dyango. Python server is 2.6.6 and for Dyango can not check if know how to check?

Comment: I got this error randomly while trying to make migrations and I was in my virtual environment with Django installed. I simply ran the command again and it worked.

Comment: I have this same error. I have django installed but I it is installed in the dist-packages directory. The Dockerfile uses the ubuntu base image. So I updated the Dockerfile to add this `ENV PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages"` but it still not loading the django app.

Answer (score 58):

It sounds like you do not have django installed. You should check the directory produced by this command:

```
python -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib; print get_python_lib()"
```

To see if you have the django packages in there.

If there's no django folder inside of site-packages, then you do not have django installed (at least for that version of python).

It is possible you have more than one version of python installed and django is inside of another version. You can find out all the versions of python if you type `python` and then press TAB. Here are all the different python's I have.

```
$python
python            python2-config    python2.6         python2.7-config  pythonw2.5
python-config     python2.5         python2.6-config  pythonw           pythonw2.6
python2           python2.5-config  python2.7         pythonw2          pythonw2.7
```

You can do the above command for each version of python and look inside the site-packages directory of each to see if any of them have django installed. For example:

```
python2.5 -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib; print get_python_lib()"
python2.6 -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib; print get_python_lib()"
```

If you happen to find django inside of say python2.6, try your original command with

```
python2.6 manage.py ...
```

Comment: This is what comes right after the command "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages"

Comment: Go into the folder "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages" and see if there's a folder called django inside.

Comment: Evrything else not Django :D

Comment: Hi, please check my edited answer. Maybe your django is in another version of python.

Comment: I checked but could not find other versions of python

Comment: Then it's safe to say your host has not installed django. :) If my answer was helpful, please +1. Thanks.

Comment: Let them have already reported problems. I reached on +1 reputation as otherwise I would have given you +1 :)

Comment: Here's what I replied to the host company

Hello
These frameworks only work for fastcgi, the rules you set them in. htaccess file, then documentation frameworks were you use.

Comment: If you installed django using virtualenv or while on a virtual environment, you have to be in the virtual environment for it to run, unless you have installed it in the system globally.

Answer (score 47):

```
sudo pip install django --upgrade
```

did the trick for me.

Comment: Your answer worked for me, so I gave it an upvote. However, just your answer alone wasn't enough, because when I ran `sudo pip install django --upgrade` it gave me a new error: `No module named psycopg2`. So, I ran `sudo pip install psycopg2 --upgrade`, and it did the trick.

Comment: Turned out I didn't have django installed...Even though I'd used it before on the machine. Weird.

Comment: I had a timeout issue so I did `sudo pip install --default-timeout=100 django --upgrade` and it all went smoothly.

Comment: If you are using "pyenv" you would need the following : `pip install django --upgrade --user`

Answer (score 30):

I got the same error and I fixed it in this manner:

I had to activate my virtual environment using the following command

```
source python2.7/bin/activate
```

Answer (score 22):

Most probably in your `manage.py` the first line starts with `!/usr/bin/python` which means you are using the system global python rather than the one in your virtual environment.

so replace

```
/usr/bin/python
```

with

```
~/projectpath/venv/bin/python
```

and you should be good.

Comment: Thanks. It helped.

Comment: My project had a bash script that called one portion of the app, and in that bash script was ```python startapp``` so I had to change it to ```/path/to/venv/bin/python startapp``` and it worked. Thank you for pointing this out!!

Answer (score 14):

well, I faced the same error today after installing virtualenv and django. For me it was that I had used sudo (**sudo pip install django**) for installing django, and I was trying to run the **manage.py runserver** without **sudo**. I just added sudo and it worked. :)

Answer (score 10):

Are you using a Virtual Environment with Virtual Wrapper?  Are you on a Mac?

If so try this:

Enter the following into your command line to start up the virtual environment and then work on it

1.)

```
source virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

or

```
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

2.)

```
workon [environment name]
```

Note (from a newbie) - do not put brackets around your environment name

Comment: It took me like two seconds to figure out that virtualenv was not enabled, but this was my problem...so upvote since i hit google the google button once and didn't read anything that came up.

Answer (score 7):

I am having the same problem while running the command-

> python manage.py startapp < app_name >

but problem with me is that i was running that command out of virtual environment.So just activate your virtual environment first and run the command again -

Comment: My project had a bash script that called one portion of the app, and in that bash script was ```python startapp``` so I had to change it to ```/path/to/venv/bin/python startapp``` and it worked.

Answer (score 6):

The problem occurs when django isn't installed on your computer. You also get this error because the django.core.management module is missing.

To solve this issue we have to install django using pip. Open a command line prompt -> cmd(on windows) and enter the following command:

```
pip install django
```

This command will install django on your computer. So consider installing pip first. [Here's how to install pip on a Windows machine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36277641/4104008)

Answer (score 6):

I experience the same thing and this is what I do.

First my installation of

> pip install -r requirements.txt

is not on my active environment. So I did is activate my environment then run again the

> pip install -r requirements.txt

Answer (score 4):

Okay so it goes like this:

You have created a virtual environment and django module belongs to that environment only.Since virtualenv isolates itself from everything else,hence you are seeing this.

go through this for further assistance:

http://www.swegler.com/becky/blog/2011/08/27/python-django-mysql-on-windows-7-part-i-getting-started/

1.You can switch to the directory where your virtual environment is stored and then run the django module.

2.Alternatively you can install django globally to your python->site-packages by either running pip or easy_install

Command using pip: pip install django

then do this:

import django print (django.get_version()) (depending on which version of python you use.This for python 3+ series)

and then you can run this: python manage.py runserver and check on your web browser by typing :localhost:8000 and you should see django powered page.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

In case this is helpful to others... I had this issue because my virtualenv defaulted to python2.7 and I was calling Django using Python3 while using Ubuntu.

to check which python my virtualenv was using:

```
$ which python3
>> /usr/bin/python3
```

created new virtualenv with python3 specified (using virtualenv wrapper https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/):

```
$ mkvirtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python3 ENV_NAME
```

the python path should now point to the virtualenv python:

```
$ which python3
>> /home/user/.virtualenvs/ENV_NAME/bin/python3
```

Answer (score 2):

This also happens if you change the directory structure of your python project (I did this, and then puzzled over the change in behavior).  If you do so, you'll need to change a line in your /bin/activate file.  So, say your project was at

```
/User/me/CodeProjects/coolApp/
```

and your activate file is at

```
/User/me/CodeProjects/coolApp/venv/bin/activate
```

when you set up your project, then you changed your project to

```
/User/me/CodeProjects/v1-coolApp/
```

or something.  You would then need to open

```
/User/me/CodeProjects/v1-coolApp/venv/bin/activate
```

find the line where it says

```
VIRTUAL_ENV="/User/me/CodeProjects/coolApp"
export VIRTUAL_ENV
```

and change it to

```
VIRTUAL_ENV="/User/me/CodeProjects/v1-coolApp"
```

before reactivating

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I am using Ubuntu. The problem can be that I don't have the permission to write to that folder as a normal user. You can simply add the `sudo` before your command and it should work perfectly. In my case `sudo python manage.py syncdb`.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and the reason I was getting this message was because I was doing "manage.py runserver" whereas doing "python manage.py runserver" fixed it.

Comment: Note that if Python 3 is used it needs to be `python3 manage.py runserver`. Otherwise import error will still be there.

Answer (score 2):

My case I used pyCharm 5 on mac. I also had this problem and after running this command my problem was solved

```
sudo pip install django --upgrade
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and following worked good, you should navigate main folder in your project than type:

```
source bin/activate
```

Answer (score 1):

had the same problem.run command 'python manage.py migrate' as root. works fine with root access (sudo python manage.py migrate )

Comment: That's kind of treating the symptom not the cause. 

If sudo works it's probably a permissions issue.

Comment: Surely, just a way to diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can try it like so : `python3 manage.py migrate` (make sur to be in the `src/` directory)

You can also try with `pip install -r requirements.txt` (make sur you see the `requirements.txt` file when you type `ls` after the migrate

If after all it still won't work try `pip install django`

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem trying to use the **python manage.py runserver**. In my case I just use **sudo su**. Use the terminal as a root and  try it again an it works partially. So I use  **python manage.py migrate** comand and it fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You must choose your Project first before running the server , type this
`workon your_project_name`
then 
`python manage.py runserver`

Answer (score 0):

It is because of virtual enviornment configuration. You need to work on your virtual enviornmnet of Python. You should try on your command promt with,

```
workon virtual_enviornment_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Run following command

```
python3 manage.py runserver
```

Instead of

```
python manage.py runserver
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

File and Directory ownership conflict will cause issues here.  Make sure the ownership of the directories and files under the project are to the current user.  (You can change them using the chown command with the -R option.) Try rerunning the command: this solved the problem for me when running through the "First Django App" sample:

```
python manage.py startapp polls
```