# ImportError: No module named django.core.management when using manage.py

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, importerror, django-manage.py

I'm trying to run `python manage.py runserver` on a Django application I have and I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
 from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named django.core.management
```

Here is the output of `pip freeze | grep -i django` to show I do in fact have Django installed:

```
Django==1.6.5
django-cached-authentication-middleware==0.2.0
django-cors-headers==1.1.0
django-htmlmin==0.7.0
django-static-precompiler==0.9
djangorestframework==2.3.14
```

Also, trying to run `/usr/local/bin/python2.7 manage.py runserver` yields the same error.

Comment: did u run the command from where manage.py is at?

Comment: And how many versions of pythons are running on ur machine?

Comment: are you using a virtual environment for this purpose? can you share the details of your settings file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To fix my problem I used the following line in my .zprofile:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

I was trying to import Django and it couldn't be found, and doing the above solved the issue.

Comment: in case an error is shown that 'export is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file, change EXPORT to SET, i.e., set PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages

Comment: is there any way to configure the python path permanently? because I have to run the above command every time I open a cmd window

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. Only solution I've found so far that has worked.

Comment: Did same but still got same error /django_project$ python manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    ) from exc

Answer (score 31):

Possible issues that may cause your problem:

1. PYTHONPATH is not well configured, to configure it you should do:

   ```
   export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
   ```
2. You forgot the line `#!/usr/bin/env python` at the beginning of manage.py
3. If you're working on virtualenv you forgot to activate the virtual env to execute manage.py commands (You may have installed Django on your system but not on your virtualenv)

   ```
   source path/to/your/virtualenv/bin/activate
   ```

   or

   ```
   workon env_name
   ```
4. You have Python 2.7 and Python 3.4 messing with the package
5. You're using a very old Python 2.4 and you should tell the system to use your Python 2.7 with:

   ```
   alias python=python2.7
   ```

Some times reinstalling/upgrading Django fix some of those issues.

You may want to execute

```
python -c "import django; print(django.get_version())"
```

to check if Django is installed on your PC or your virtualenv if you're using one

You can find some other solutions in other similar questions:

- [Django import error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6049933/django-import-error-no-module-named-core-management)
- [Django uwsgi error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30389771/importerror-no-module-named-django-core-management-when-using-manage-py)
- [Django module error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14013728/django-no-module-named-django-core-management)

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I'm not sure about how to set up my PYTHONPATH correctly. Can you give me more insight?

Regarding the rest, I do have #2 correct, for #3 I'm not using a virtual environment, so that shouldn't be the problem, for #4 and #5 I have `python` running a shell with Python 2.7.6 so I think I'm fine there. Also, I've since reinstalled Django but I'm still having the issue.

Comment: In my case it was number 3: I forgot to activate the virtual environment. A simple: `source bin/activate`, and solved :)

Answer (score 4):

I solved this same error by running the below command:

```
python3.4 manage.py runserver
```

And the above command successfully executed for me. So what you can try is, if you are using python 2.7 then just replace 3.4 with 2.7. Hope this helps.

Comment: this one saved my day... After much struggling, I just changed `python2.7 manage.py changepassword` instead of `python manage.py changepassword` and voilá!

Answer (score 3):

I came across the same issue when I did all the setup and run for django with Python3 but ran the following command:

```
$ python manage.py migrate
```

fixed the issue by using a consistent version of Python:

```
$ python3 manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: sessions, auth, admin, contenttypes
Running migrations:
  Rendering model states... DONE
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0002_logentry_remove_auto_add... OK
  Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... OK
  Applying auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts... OK
  Applying auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null... OK
  Applying auth.0006_require_contenttypes_0002... OK
  Applying auth.0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages... OK
  Applying sessions.0001_initial... OK
```

Other commands I ran before this were:

```
python3 -m pip install django
django-admin startproject learning_site
python3 manage.py  runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use `virtualenv` and run `manage.py runserver` in windows system, cmd will use system's python, not the python in virtualenv. 
Because If you install `python` in system, cmd will automatically use `python` that installed in system, not the python in `virtualenv`. 
So if you use `virtualenv` in Windows. you need run

```
>python .\manage.py runserver
```

Answer (score 1):

That error is due to the user environment. Indeed i just add the virtuel environment bin path to  PATH and the problem has been solved.

```
PATH=/bin/of_virtualenvironment/:$PATH
```

Answer (score 1):

The direct problem is that django package is missing. For me, as I was running django in virtualenv, this problem occurs after I rename my working directory.

Reinstalling the env worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

in where your django file resides, check the first line of django-admin.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

If you use python 3+, `python` here may refers python2 here. So check which python you install django with.

```
ls -l $(which -a python3)
```

If you do have python3 installed and not linked as `python`, change the first shebang line into

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

Comment: I think I misunderstand your question since you do use `python manage.py` to indicate the environment. Just check which `python` you install django with and use that `python`. You may have to change the PYTHONPATH or PATH to indicate which python to use.

Answer (score 0):

Also, make sure you did not mess up your `.bashrc` with `alias`es.
You would get this kind of errors if `.bashrc` contains something like `alias python="/usr/bin/python3"`.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I could import the django module from the python interpreter, but django-admin.py could not import it when run from the command line.

I confirmed that I was using the python interpreter in my virtual environment.

I was using a 64-bit version of python. Uninstalling, and installing the 32-bit version, then re-creating my venv solved this for me.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the same problem in my project using only;

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

I didn't have to do anything else. When I ran`./manage.py runserver` everything worked!

Answer (score 0):

Using Pycharm go to Configurations add **runserver 8080**
to parameters, or I fixed my issue by restarting my computer....strange but worked.
I did not have to change pip or install anything else, first try the first method I listed, if you are fine with running manage.py through PyCharm arrow icon, it will work, if you want to go back to the terminal and type python manage.py runserver:port try restarting your machine.

Answer (score 0):

Trying the solutions here didn't work for me. Reinstalling Django and upgrading pip removed the error and everything now works as expected when I run **python migrate.py runserver**

Here are the CLI commands I used:

> python -m pip install django

> python -m pip install --upgrade pip

Answer (score -1):

i solved this problem by installing django inside the virtual enviromment that i was working on

Comment: This is quite vague. Could you explain a little bit what exactly you did and how and why that answers the question?