# makemigrations django no modul named django.core.management

Tags: django

```
manage.py makemigrations 
Traceback(most recent call last):
\manage.py, line 8 in <module>
from djang.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named django.core.management
```

The server still runs/website will function, however when `manage.py makemigrations` ran the above error is shown.

Comment: are you using a virtualenv?  did you forget to activate it?

Comment: python manage.py makemigrations, close thread

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django - "no module named django.core.management"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14013728/django-no-module-named-django-core-management)

Comment: `from djang.core.management` where is the o of django?

Comment: probably a typo in the question, it's spelled right in the ImportError

Comment: If your are using a virtualenv make sure that you have installed django and your virtualenv is activated.