# How to create superuser in django using Unix Environment

Tags: python, django, unix

when I'm using Visual Studio Code for the Django project in windows Environment, for creating a superuser I'm using the below command.

```
(test) C:\Users\SAHEB\projects\project>python manage.py createsuperuser
```

this same Django project is deployed in Unix server, below is the path where whole project is deployed.

```
/apps/sample/python
```

but `python manage.py createsuperuser` this command is not working in Unix server from this path, what's the solution

Answer (score 0):

[from_the_docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/django-admin/#runserver): runserver is to start a server and not to create superuser.

[from_the_docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/django-admin/#createsuperuser): To create superuser run following command:

```
django-admin createsuperuser
```

Comment: Sorry, I put the wrong command, I have edited my question.Thanks

Comment: django-admin createsuperuser command is not working in unix environment

Comment: are you running it from same directory as **manage.py** ?

Comment: yes from the same directory, it's showing there is no subcommand like 'createsuperuser'

Comment: what error or infomation are you getting? what it says? what's output when you run **python manage.py createsuperuser**?

Comment: python manage.py createsuperuser                                                              
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named django.core.management

Comment: you sure you have **django** installed in your test environment? you can see list of installed libraries/modules using `pip freeze`. what's output of `pip freeze | grep django` are you getting?

Comment: Django==1.8 is installed, I have checked requirment.txt file

Comment: checkout this question and let know: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14013728/django-no-module-named-django-core-management

Comment: also instead of checkint requirements.txt manually can you can try running `pip freeze | grep django` to make sure you have it installed in the python environment you are using to run this command.

Comment: after using  'pip freeze | grep django ' it's not showing any version of python

Comment: hmm, this means that django isn't installed in your current python environment. try running: *pip install -r requirements.txt"

Comment: Is it possible to check in which environment Django is installed in unix server?

Comment: ^idk, be safe to install requirement.txt so everything is up-to-date. you can also install using **--user** flag if you don't have admin permissions.

Answer (score 0):

`python manage.py createsuperuser` works on all platforms. I think it's because of your path. Type `dir` and press enter in your cmd (make sure you do it in your project directory) at let's see if there is a file called `manage.py` or not.

```
(test) C:\Users\SAHEB\projects\project>dir
```

Comment: command successfully working in the windows environment but not working in Unix environment.